# Emacs erlang-mode indent too deeply

Tags: emacs, erlang

This is what I want:

```
get_exc_info() ->
    db_agent:select_row(exc_sit, 
      "begin_exc_time, total_exc_time, last_logout_time", 
      [{player_id, Player#player.id}].
```

Now it's the following style:

```
get_exc_info() ->
    db_agent:select_row(exc_sit, 
                        "begin_exc_time, total_exc_time, last_logout_time", 
                        [{player_id, Player#player.id}].
```

Is there anyway to modify? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've seen, functions with long names or with extra long argument names are usually indented as follows:

```
foo() ->
    bar_the_long_one(
      FirstArgumentWithExtraLongName,
      SecondArgumentWithExtraLongName),
```

In this case you can set argument indent with `erlang-argument-indent` variable.